# How do I find out if string contains multiple letters/characters using regex?

Tags: java, regex

In Java, is there a way to find out if string contains multiple letters/characters using Regular Expressions/ Pattern matching?

I have tried to solve my problem using below code

```
      String id = "A12B45";

      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]*");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(id);

      if (matcher.find()) 
              {
          System.out.println("YES---");
      } else 
              {
          System.out.println("NO---");
      }
```

The above code is not giving me an output which I want. When string contains more than one alphabet letter then it should return "YES---".
Can you please help?

Comment: Do you mean you want to print `YES---` when the string contains more than one letter consecutively? For example `AK12B45` should print `YES---` (because it contains A followed immediately by K) but `A12B45` should print `NO---` ?

Comment: Your question is not clear..What do you mean by 'string contains more than one alphabet letter ' is it anywhere in the string or consecutive occurrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match an alphabetical character, then anything but alphabetical characters, then an alphabetical character again:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z]");
```